# How do I install dask_cudf?

Tags: python, installation, dask, rapids, cudf

I am using the follow lines in terminal to install rapids and then dask cudf:

```
conda create -n rapids-core-0.14 -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge \
     -c defaults rapids=0.14 python=3.7 cudatoolkit=10.1
conda activate rapids-core-0.14
conda install -c rapidsai dask-cudf
```

but when I go to import dask_cudf into the python notebook:

```
import dask_cudf
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-827f6c5d8016> in <module>
      9 from dask.distributed import Client
     10 from dask.utils import parse_bytes
---> 11 import dask_cudf
     12 np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': lambda x: "{0:0.4f}".format(x)})
     13 pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.5f' % x)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dask_cudf'
```

Why is it unable to find the module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended installation command to Conda install RAPIDS is the following:

```
conda create -n rapids-0.17 -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge \
    -c defaults rapids-blazing=0.17 python=3.7 cudatoolkit=10.1
```

Note that you may need to change the CUDA Toolkit version depending on your system. You can find this command (and other installation options) on the [Getting Started](https://rapids.ai/start#get-rapids) page.

You may also want to double check that the Python you are using is in fact the one from the Conda environment. This can usually be done with `which python`.